# Do magic and ghosts exist in the Addams Family's world?

Tags: ghost, addams-family

Between Gate [their "pet" gate which seems to be sentient, romping with people and opening up for them], Morticia saying she studied "spells and casting", Granny/Mama working over her cauldron in the 1991 movie, and especially Thing, I'm guessing this would be a given. But it's never implicitly said or shown this magic "working" in real life...well, except for the presence of Thing.

"Ghosts" or departed spirits seemed to have been mentioned specifically before, though. So, should we take it for granted that,in general, actual supernatural /paranormal elements are just a given, or is it that things being "mysterious and spooky" are particular to the Addams Family themselves?

Or perhaps...might this more be a case of the "magical real"?

Answer (score 4):

The members of the Addams Family were clearly preternatural in their television show incarnation.  For example, Uncle Fester could power light bulbs in his mouth, which would not be possible without magic.

Comment: Yeah, but a lot of that could be explained away by the style of "exaggerated comedy" which was popular at the time. Shows like _Bewitched, My Favorite Martian_ and _I Dream of Jeannie_  had **explicit reasons** for their characters doing less than normal things. The Addams' closest analog, _The Munsters_ were also "shown" to be supernatural. The Addams in their 60s show, more or less, could possibly just be seen as "eccentric" with a high threshold for pain and a family taste for both the macabre, and unusual sight gags. It was never clearly _said_ they were "more than human", though.

Comment: I'd also say there could be non-magical, scientific (or at least pseudo-scientific) reasons for many of the quirks of the family. For instance, there are real world examples of animals which can generate and output electricity, and certainly plenty of fictional, yet non-magical, examples of humans who can produce extreme heat (e.g. human torch).

Comment: Emphasis on the pseudo part. The main difference between the Human Torch and a wizard is that his incantations ("Flame on") are mostly for show.

Comment: Vampira smoked too! https://youtu.be/0HXUt4kMoBE